# Migrate jenkins jobs to script pipeline for ClearCase plugin

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I am migrating my jenkins jobs to pipeline script.
In my build job, I use ClearCase plugin:
[BaseClearCase Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcrmU.png)

Now I find in pipeline script, I can use Pipeline SCM Step($class: ClearCaseSCM). 
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

But I don't know how to configure it. Does anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have tried, and the exact error message you got? What version of ClearCase are you using? on which OS?

Comment: Thanks VonC. My OS is Win7, and ClearCase should be 8.0.1. In fact, I have not tried it now, because there is no examples on the sytax guide, and I am not familiar with CC. I'll update this ticket later.